# Apple WatchOS2 - can I run an app forever, until the device runs out of power?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos-2, background-foreground

I'm interested in using Apple Watch for sleep studies. This requires collecting data from accelerometer and potentially heart rate sensor over extended periods of time.

**Does watchOS2 allow me as a developer to run an app in the foreground until the battery runs out?**

Or will the watchOS force my app to become suspended as a result of wrist gestures or timeout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no legitimate way to prevent the watch from going to sleep.

Your app would, presumably, also need methods to prevent the side button and crown from performing their default functions, and such methods do not exist.

Comment: Are those buttons sensitive enough to be disturbed by moving a hand with the watch under blankets?

Comment: I would think not, but they can definitely be pressed by the wearers hand when they flex their wrist (as demonstrated by the myriad screenshots I've accidentally taken by pressing both buttons at the same time).